# How to find class name inside a bunch of jars

Tags: eclipse

I have a whole lot of jar files in my system , related to my Application .

How can i find  a particular class in that whole lot of jar files ??

Thank you

Comment: You might want to ask this on `superuser.com` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate > http://superuser.com/questions/285793/finding-which-jars-contain-a-file

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If those jar files are in the build path of your Eclipse project:

Ctrl-Shift-T (for "Open Type", "type" as in "class") brings up a search box. You can CamelType (i.e. SB instead of StringBuilder).

Comment: Doesn't CTRL + T opens `Type Hierarchy of "Class"`

Comment: Oops. Maybe Ctrl-shift-T. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much , actually i mean in a Windows Folder , i have a lot of jars , i want to import only the required jars into Eclipse , sorry for the confusion .

Comment: You can open them with 7Zip (or something similar, jar files are just zip files) and see what is inside.

Comment: Is it possible to pro-grammatically derive jar name in java, equivalent to Ctrl + Shift + T ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to right-click on the class name in a source file and select one of the sub-items of the <kbd>Declarations</kbd> context menu item - i.e., right click on the class name and select <kbd>Declarations</kbd>/<kbd>Project</kbd>.  This will search the project for any declarations of the class and pop up the standard Eclipse search results view.  I am assuming that you have the jar as a library in your Eclipse project.

If you want to do this on the file system instead, then use a for loop to iterate over the JAR files and use `jar tf FILENAME` to get the list of class files and pipe that through `grep` or `findstr` (depending on your platform).  If you are using `bash`, something like the following would do the trick:

```
bash-3.2$ for f in *.jar
do
  result=$(jar tf $f | grep '/DBObject.class$')
  [ -n "$result" ] && echo "$f contains $result"
done
mongodb-api-2.6.3.jar contains com/mongodb/DBObject.class
bash-3.2$
```

You could concoct something similar in Windows using a `FOR` loop at a command prompt but I don't recall if `FINDSTR` sets the result `ERRORLEVEL` correctly.  The following should work not completely sure of the syntax:

```
C:\Directory\Containing\Jars> FOR %I IN (*.jar) DO @(
  FOR /F %J IN ('jar tf %I') DO ECHO "%J: %I"
) | FINDSTR /R /C:"/DBObject.class$"
mongodb-api-2.6.3.jar: com/mongodb/DBObject.class
C:\Directory\Containing\Jars>
```

*If I remember, I'll edit this after I get to a Windows machine.*

Comment: any chance for recursive search (windows case)?